# Phone app uses a single contact's image for all calls

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Since I've updated to iOS 7, there's something that has driven me nearly insane every time I make a phone call. Every time I receive or place a call, the background image for the call (which is supposed to be the contact's image) consistently shows up the same for all calls. This would be fine if it were my wallpaper, but it's actually a picture of someone that I used for their contact photo. I've since deleted the photo from my phone and from the contact, but it still shows up for every phone call I receive.

As you can expect, this is extremely bothering. Is there any way to clear the cache that is used for contact photos on phone calls?

Answer (score 1):

Try a reset all settings it worked fine for me.
Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings.

The phone will reboot and the problem will be fixed but the custom settings like wallpaper and lock screen wallpaper will be reset to iOS 7 default.